# How to use digression in dialogflow?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, dialogflow-es, watson-conversation

Is there a way to digress in `dialogflow`, similar to what is offered by Watson assistant?

For example:

> User: I need to change my phone number?
>   Bot: Please provide your account number.
>   User: Can you tell me about home insurance?
>   Bot: `<<insurance details>>`
>   Bot: Please provide your account number.
>   User:...

This is possible in watson such that user can digress to FAQ or any other unrelated intent and then resume the conversation from where he left.

Comment: I think you can handle most of this by controlling the lifetimes of context parameters.  Not sure how you’d get it to reprompt though without doing that in custom fulfillment logic... maybe when you ask the user a question, you store that question in context and then your fulfillment webhook can check if their is a pending prompt from another intent and if so appent that prompt to the response of whatever intent is currently being handled?